# $ \{(b\overline{a},1);\;(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2\}=\mathbb{C}\times \{1\} $

Tags: complex-numbers

Let us consider the following subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$

$$
S=\{(b\overline{a},1);\;(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2\}.
$$

> I want to prove that $S=\mathbb{C}\times \{1\}$. We have $S\subset\mathbb{C}\times \{1\}$

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: How to write every complex number $z$ as $b \bar a$?

Comment: Then try a couple. Write $5$ as $b\bar a$. Write $\sqrt2i$ and $1+i$ as $b\bar a$. Can you do all of them in the "same way" in some way?

Comment: I think we can solve the problem via the polar decomposition.

Comment: It's a lot easier than that. You can choose both $a$ and $b$ freely, and I suspect that maybe the amount of freedom is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a=1$ and choose any $b\in\mathbb{C}$ then $b\overline{a}=b$ is an arbitrary complex number. Hence we have that $\mathbb{C}\times\{1\}\subseteq S$. Also we require $b\overline{a}$ to be complex as $\mathbb{C}$ is closed under multiplication. Hence $S\subseteq\mathbb{C}\times\{1\}$. These two facts imply that $S=\mathbb{C}\times\{1\}$.